# How to work with Jasmine 3.3 or above in Protractor?

Tags: jasmine, protractor

It comes with Jasmine 2.8 by default and I cannot find any way to change it.

in my config file, I can set framework (jasmine, mocha) but not the version

the only thing I could find was this github issue but can't find anything about why it was rolled back and how to work with 3.3 plus now.

https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/5102

Comment: Oh hey look! It's my pull request. Yup, the entire release was rolled back by the Angular team. I don't know what else I can say about it. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Then answer by [yong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65595138/1705056) didn't worked for me. The reason is that you need to provide a wrapper for jasmine, not jasmine itself.

This is what worked for me with Protractor 7.0.0 and jasmine 3.10.0.

It works use the jasmine2 adapter of Protractor.

1. Instruct protractor to use jasmine 3

This is easily done with yarn resolutions, e.g.

```
"resolutions": {
    ...
    "**/jasmine": "^3.10.0",
},
```

2. Create a NOOP jasminewd2 file

```
exports.init = () => {
    console.log('Using mock-jasminewd2 to remove jasminewd2 from protractor');
};
```

And instruct protractor to use it instead of jasminewd2, again using yarn workspaces

```
"resolutions": {
    ...
    "**/jasminewd2": "file:./packages/mock-jasminewd2"
},
```

We don't need jasminewd2 when we use proper async matchers of jasmine3

3. Rewrite all custom matchers that returned promise in "pass" to proper jasmine 3 async matchers, e.g.
   https://github.com/tepez/jasmine-protractor-matchers/commit/c6e2092d1f925a415b1192303b57da4a5790439a
4. Add the custom matchers using `jasmine.addAsyncMatchers` instead of `jasmine.addMatchers`
5. Rewrite all expectations:

`await expect(...)` => `await expectAsync(...)`

6. Disable jasmine's random onPrepare

```
jasmine.getEnv().configure({
    random: false,
});
```

This can't be done by passing random in jasmineNodeOpts

Note that master branch of protractor has version 6 code which is very different from version 7
which is more like 5.

So browse it's code https://github.com/angular/protractor/tree/7.0.0
instead that of the master branch https://github.com/angular/protractor

This can be confusing because version 6 [does disable](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/6.0.0/lib/frameworks/jasmine.js#L76) randomness of jasmine

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try as following:

1. add Jasmine 3.3 as dependency. Please confirm the Jamsine version after `npm install`
2. customize test framework in conf.js

```
exports.config = {
    ...
    framework: "custom",
    frameworkPath: require.resolve("jasmine"),
    ...
}
```